# Right mouse click on WebBuild

Tags: c#, html, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make my game have the ability to right mouse button click on web builds.

```
void MouseCheck()
{
  if(Input.GetMouseButton(1))
  {
     //my code
  }
}
```

But it doesn't get detected because when I right click in web build it shows some default options such as `full screen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, but not impossible.

You need to make changes on the built's `HTML`. This is how you would do it:

```
var params = 
{
    disableContextMenu: true,
};
```

This parameter will notify Unity Web Player whether it should display the `ContextMenu` or not. This in turn prevents the context menu from appearing, which then allows your game to check for Right-Mouse Clicks.

Here is a link to all the customization you can do to the `HTML` file: [Unity WebPlayer's Behaviours](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/WebPlayerBehaviorTags.html).

---

It is important that you include the `C#` code which does the actual right click checks happen.

```
 if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
 {
    // Code here.
 }
```

*This was added for future readers who might benefit from this part*